# Multiple searchTerm

Tags: vb.net, linq, search, count, datasource

I have the following code trying to find how many times the specific word occurs in the given text. The code works but for only one parameter in the given example for "Dim searchTerm As String = "data". I would like to search for multiple words for example: "data", "separate", "node" etc.
Could someone please help me to modify the existing code to archive the task?

```
Class CountWords

Shared Sub Main()

    Dim text As String = "Historically, the world of data and the world of objects" &
              " have not been well integrated. Programmers work in C# or Visual Basic" &
              " and also in SQL or XQuery. On the one side are concepts such as classes," &
              " objects, fields, inheritance, and .NET Framework APIs. On the other side" &
              " are tables, columns, rows, nodes, and separate languages for dealing with" &
              " them. Data types often require translation between the two worlds; there are" &
              " different standard functions. Because the object world has no notion of query, a" &
              " query can only be represented as a string without compile-time type checking or" &
              " IntelliSense support in the IDE. Transferring data from SQL tables or XML trees to" &
              " objects in memory is often tedious and error-prone."

    Dim searchTerm As String = "data"

    ' Convert the string into an array of words.
    Dim dataSource As String() = text.Split(New Char() {" ", ",", ".", ";", ":"},
                                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    ' Create and execute the query. It executes immediately
    ' because a singleton value is produced.
    ' Use ToLower to match "data" and "Data"
    Dim matchQuery = From word In dataSource
                  Where word.ToLowerInvariant() = searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
                  Select word

    ' Count the matches.
    Dim count As Integer = matchQuery.Count()
    Console.WriteLine(count & " occurrence(s) of the search term """ &
                      searchTerm & """ were found.")

    ' Keep console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Class
' Output:
' 3 occurrence(s) of the search term "data" were found.

Comment: Do you need the total of occurances of all the words "data", "separate", "node"? Or do you need separate totals for each word?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need separate total for each word, but not always the same words they should be dynamic to be able to change them and and to search for more than 3.

Comment: List of words ex. File.txt and count each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is cool but it just does the loops internally so it is not necessarily faster.

```
Module Module1
        Public Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim SearchTerms() As String = {"data".ToLowerInvariant, "separate".ToLowerInvariant, "nodes".ToLowerInvariant}
            Dim Count = GetCount(SearchTerms)
            Dim SearchTerm = String.Join(", ", SearchTerms)
            Console.WriteLine($"{Count} occurrence(s) of the search terms {SearchTerm} were found.")
            ' Keep console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.")
            Console.ReadKey()
        End Sub
    
        Private Function GetCount(SearchTerms As String()) As Integer
            Dim text As String = "Historically, the world of data and the world of objects
                   have not been well integrated. Programmers work in C# or Visual Basic
                   and also in SQL or XQuery. On the one side are concepts such as classes,
                   objects, fields, inheritance, and .NET Framework APIs. On the other side
                   are tables, columns, rows, nodes, and separate languages for dealing with
                   them. Data types often require translation between the two worlds; there are
                   different standard functions. Because the object world has no notion of query, a
                   query can only be represented as a string without compile-time type checking or
                   IntelliSense support in the IDE. Transferring data from SQL tables or XML trees to
                   objects in memory is often tedious and error-prone."
            Dim dataSource As String() = text.Split(New Char() {" "c, ","c, "."c, ";"c, ":"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Dim Count As Integer
            For Each item In dataSource
                'If you want to have a variable number of SearchTerms make a nested For
                If item.ToLowerInvariant = SearchTerms(0) Or item.ToLowerInvariant = SearchTerms(1) Or item.ToLowerInvariant = SearchTerms(2) Then
                    Count += 1
                End If
            Next
            Return Count
        End Function

End Module
```